# Did Donald Trump leak his own tax returns?

Tags: donald-trump, taxes

Part of Trump's tax returns for 2005 were leaked yesterday. Some source claim that Trump leaked them, while others say he didnt ([1](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/politics/wp/2017/03/15/why-trump-is-not-the-most-likely-source-for-the-leaked-tax-returns/?utm_term=.a3b5aeec2471), [2](http://www.cnn.com/2017/03/15/politics/journalist-says-its-possible-tax-returns-came-from-trump-cnntv/), [3](http://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/who-leaking-donald-trump-s-tax-returns-n733661), [4](http://www.newyorker.com/news/john-cassidy/who-leaked-part-of-donald-trumps-2005-federal-tax-return), [5](http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/did-trumps-tax-returns-leak-because-he-once-sued-a-reporter-for-doubting-his-wealth/article/2617407)).

Is there any credible evidence showing that Trump did or did not leak the documents?

Comment: I thought current events are off-topic.

Comment: @fredsbend I proposed an edit as suggested [here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/550/14622).

Comment: @fredsbend They aren't, but they are special cases. http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/550/2099 - unfortunately I lack the reputation to suggest the proper edit.

Comment: The thing about leaking through anonymous sources is that 1) there is no evidence on who the source is and 2) even if there is, it's not credible unless there's an investigation. All we can do is ask "Qui bono?" but that only tells us who the source would have been if everyone was smart and clairvoyant.

Comment: Closed because there's no notable claim that Trump leaked the document as a fact. People are openly speculating and asking questions, but that does not constitute a claim. Besides it's quite unclear what evidence could be provided at this point in time on the matter.

Comment: @Sklivvz Johnston himself is claiming it. He received it in the mail with a "client copy" stamp. http://www.cnbc.com/2017/03/14/trump-may-have-leaked-his-own-tax-return-award-winning-journalist-says.html

Comment: He's claiming that Trump *may* have leaked it. It's not a statement of fact.

Comment: While we're in totally uncorroborated speculation mode, I read somewhere that journalist A sent Trump information that he said he was going to publish it and Trump 'leaked' information to journalist B. So depending on interpretation, the answer to the question title could be both yes and no.

Comment: @Sklivvz - evidence: Trump tweet? (*me runs and hides*)